# How to set Space between Y-Axis in Coreplot

Tags: ios, iphone, graph, core-plot

I have been working on CorePlot.I have set the intervals between y-Axis but it look like Overlapping.
Please check Screen shot below attached. Here is my code setting y-Axis in plot

```
CGFloat yMax=55;
    CGFloat yMin=50;
    CGFloat yInterval=0;
    yInterval=(yMax-yMin)/4;

    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
    y.labelFormatter = formatter;
    y.labelOffset = 2.0f;
    y.labelAlignment = CPTAlignmentLeft;
    y.labelTextStyle = axisTitleStyle;
    y.tickDirection = CPTSignNegative;
    y.majorTickLength = 3.0f;
    y.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromDouble(yInterval);
    y.majorGridLineStyle = gridLineStyle;
    y.gridLinesRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(yMax)];
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 1;
    y.minorTickLength = 2.0f;
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0);
    axisSet.xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromDouble(yMin-yInterval);

    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(dateCount)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMin-yInterval) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yMax+yMin)];
```

---

please Guide me how give space between y-Axis points [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posted screenshot is correct. The space between tick marks on the y-axis (`yInterval`) is (55 - 50) / 4 = 1.25. The `yRange` has a location of 50 - 1.25 = 48.75 and length 50 + 55 = 105. That means you have tick marks every 1.25 units apart in a space of 105 units, or 84 ticks and labels.

Comment: Suppose if i increase length can i see the space between every y-Axis ?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you meant `yInterval=(yMax + yMin)/4;`? That divides the length of the plot range into four parts. You'll get five tick marks if the interval happens to fall on the edges of the plot area.

Comment: Yes Eric But in my case I have  minimum value 50 and max value 55 so now  I am trying show points between those two values.Suppose if y start 0 interval 20 then look fine but it look all the points in the same line so i am trying do calculation like (yInterval=(yMax + yMin)/4;) but it look like overlap

Comment: is there any solution for this please guide me thank you

Comment: I think the problem is the `yRange`. Remember that ranges are specified with the location and length. Given the min and max values you want covered by the range, use the min value for the location and (max - min) for the length.